# Perception of echoes and myths concerning its nature in Northern America

Tags: comparative, native-american

I was recently listening to a song from the movie "The Ballad of Buster Scruggs", [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCqmTBhgAus) song to be more precise. Anyway, at some point as you can see in the video, the voice of the singer echoes in the canyon and he quickly improvises a lyric "Keep on moving Dan, don't you listen to him Dan, he is a devil not a man" referring to the personification of the echo.

So this sparkled the following question: How is the echo presented in the mythology of native tribes that lived in northern America? Are there any known myths about the echo, its nature, its origin or so? I am unsure but I think that I have come across a comparison of the ancient Greek and the native American perception of echoes, possibly by Claude Levi Strauss.

Any help is appreciated! This is my first post here, so please go easy if I am not posting this at the right place or something.